# rpart node assignment

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

Is it possible to extract the node assignment for a fitted `rpart` tree? What about when I apply the model to new data?

The idea is that I would like to use the nodes as a way to cluster my data.  In other packages (e.g. SPSS), I can save the predicted class, probabilities, and node number for further analysis.

Given how powerful R can be, I imagine there is a simple solution to this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search for corresponding node in a regression tree using rpart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102754/search-for-corresponding-node-in-a-regression-tree-using-rpart)

Comment: Also note that for the data used to fit the model (as opposed to predictions for new values), you can find this info in the `where` component of the object created by `summary.rpart`, or in the fitted rpart object itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using the partykit package:

```
library(rpart)
z.auto <- rpart(Mileage ~ Weight, car.test.frame)
library(partykit)
z.auto2 <- as.party(z.auto)
predict(z.auto2, car.test.frame[1:3,], type = "node")

# Eagle Summit 4 Ford Escort   4  Ford Festiva 4 
#              7               7               7
```

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for.