# Can I make a diagram out of R Cubist outcome?

Tags: r, diagram, regression, decision-tree

I just started using the R package `Cubist` which creates output like this:

> Cubist [Release 2.07 GPL Edition]  Tue Jul 09 19:46:48 2013
>
> Target attribute `outcome'
>
> Read 260 cases (9 attributes) from undefined.data
>
> Model:
>
> Rule 1: [26 cases, mean 0.3, range 0 to 8, est err 0.3]
>
> ```
> if
>     B4 <= 54.96766
>     B7 > 39.66716
> then
>     outcome = 0
> ```
>
> Rule 2: [48 cases, mean 0.3, range 0 to 8, est err 0.6]
>
> ```
> if
>     B1 > 56.99043
>     B5 > 74.11118
>     B6 > 155.996
> then
>     outcome = 9.1 - 0.17 B5 + 0.25 B7 + 0.15 NDVI
> ```

I can make use of the model using predict, but I would like to make a graphic of the tree. I don't see that it is possible looking at the manual, but I want to know if anyone knows of a way to do this.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify, I am looking for a diagram like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460595/how-do-i-make-a-regression-tree-like-this

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dotplot.cubist` to get a visual view of the model conditions and coefficients. Here an example:

```
library(mlbench)
library(Cubist)
library(gridExtra)
data(BostonHousing)
mod1 <- cubist(x = BostonHousing[, -14], y = BostonHousing$medv)
summary(mod1)
p1 <- dotplot(mod1, what = "splits",main='Conditions')
p2 <- dotplot(mod1, what = "coefs",main='Coefs')
grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

[image]

Comment: good answer, but I should have clarified what kind of tree diagram I was looking for. It's in the comments below the question now.

Answer (score 0):

`rpart` and `partykit` are both useful R packages for plotting tree style diagrams.

edit: see example of partykit here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797447/rpart-node-assigment)

Comment: As far as I could tell, rpart doesn't output regression formulas at the nodes, it only does mean values. I haven't looked into partykit, do you have a link to the graphics it can make?

Comment: [This give an example of how to use it](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partykit/vignettes/partykit.pdf). Although on closer reading I think it may be quite similar to rpart. Added an example to my original answer